# Applications won't start after waking up from sleep (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)

Tags: 18.04

I have recently switched to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS from Windows 10, so, I am totally new to Linux.

The problem I face is sometimes after waking up from sleep, I cannot seem to start some of the applications like Google Chrome, Firefox etc. I've tried to open System Monitor but it didn't respond as well. Even, sometimes my laptop's touch-pad doesn't respond while browsing in Files.

I've tried restarting but it gets stuck with a blank screen. I should include that I use an SSD for swap and /(root) and a second HDD as my /home. The HDD I use is in the HDD Caddy.

Also, sometimes it also gets stuck in shutdown with a Ubuntu loading page.

[System Monitor won't respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpgLF.png)